# Creating a dictionary in an existed dictionary by keeping keys python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
Dialogues = {
   "dialogue_id": "000001", 
   "dialogue_turns": [
      { "turn_number": 0,
        "interlocutor_id": "0001",
        "turn_text": "Hi, how are you?" },
      { "turn_number": 1,
        "interlocutor_id": "0002",
        "turn_text": "Hi, I'm fine thanks. And you?" },
      { "turn_number": 2,
        "interlocutor_id": "0001",
        "turn_text": "I am good too, are you coming to the class today" },
      { "turn_number": 3,
        "interlocutor_id": "0002",
        "turn_text": "Yes, see you soon.bye" },
      { "turn_number": 4,
        "interlocutor_id": "0001",
        "turn_text": "bye" }
   ]
}
```

And I want to add a nested dictionary inside it by doing some counting on data as this:

```
Dialogues_analyzed = {
   "dialogue_id": "000001", 
   "dialogue_analysis": [
      {"interlocutor_id": "0001",
       "total_turns":"3",
       "total_words":"number of words in all turns of id=1"},
      {
         {"interlocutor_id": "0002",
          "total_turns":"2",
          "total_words":"number of words in all turns of id=2"}
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I get the output without nested for loops? I tried to make a new dictionary and then merge it to primary dictionary. However, I lost the keys in new dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by " I lost the keys in new dictionary"? If you tried a solution, show it even if it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: In your example, the new dictionary is not _added_ to the previous one. Could you please shown _exactly_ how the desired output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you had

```py
# [ just copied from your example ]
Dialogues = {'dialogue_id': '000001', 'dialogue_turns': [
  {'turn_number': 0, 'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'turn_text': 'Hi, how are you?'},
  {'turn_number': 1, 'interlocutor_id': '0002', 'turn_text': "Hi, I'm fine thanks. And you?"},
  {'turn_number': 2, 'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'turn_text': 'I am good too, are you coming to the class today'},
  {'turn_number': 3, 'interlocutor_id': '0002', 'turn_text': 'Yes, see you soon.bye'},
  {'turn_number': 4, 'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'turn_text': 'bye'}]}
```

and tried

```py
dKey, iKey = 'dialogue_turns', 'interlocutor_id' ## [ just to shorten lines ]
dt_grouped = [
    (iid, [d for d in Dialogues[dKey] if d[iKey]==iid]) 
    for iid in set(dt[iKey] for dt in Dialogues[dKey])
] ## group turns by interlocutor_id
dialogue_analysis = [{
    'interlocutor_id': iid, 'total_turns': len(dt_list),
    'total_words': sum(len(dt['turn_text'].split()) for dt in dt_list)
} for iid, dt_list in dt_grouped]

Dialogues_analyzed = {  'dialogue_id': Dialogues['dialogue_id'],
                        'dialogue_analysis': dialogue_analysis  }
```

then `Dialogues_analyzed` would look like

> ```py
> {'dialogue_id': '000001',
>  'dialogue_analysis': [
>   {'interlocutor_id': '0002', 'total_turns': 2, 'total_words': 10},
>   {'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'total_turns': 3, 'total_words': 16}]}
> ```

---

If you want to add `dialogue_analysis` into `Dialogues`, you can do so with **<kbd>`Dialogues['dialogue_analysis'] = dialogue_analysis`</kbd>**; or, if you wanted to leave the original `Dialogues` unchanged, you could instead unpack it (with `**`) into a new dictionary which would also contain `dialogue_analysis`:

```py
Dialogues_with_Analysis = {**Dialogues, 'dialogue_analysis': dialogue_analysis}
```

and `Dialogues_with_Analysis` (or `Dialogues` if analysis was added to it) would look like:

> ```py
> {'dialogue_id': '000001', 
>  'dialogue_turns': [
>   {'turn_number': 0, 'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'turn_text': 'Hi, how are you?'},
>   {'turn_number': 1, 'interlocutor_id': '0002', 'turn_text': "Hi, I'm fine thanks. And you?"},
>   {'turn_number': 2, 'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'turn_text': 'I am good too, are you coming to the class today'},
>   {'turn_number': 3, 'interlocutor_id': '0002', 'turn_text': 'Yes, see you soon.bye'},
>   {'turn_number': 4, 'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'turn_text': 'bye'}],
>  'dialogue_analysis': [
>   {'interlocutor_id': '0002', 'total_turns': 2, 'total_words': 10},
>   {'interlocutor_id': '0001', 'total_turns': 3, 'total_words': 16}]}
> ```

---

---

You can also wrap the logic in a function:

```py
def analyse_dialogue(dialogue_turns:list):
    dt_grouped = [
        (iid, [d for d in dialogue_turns if d['interlocutor_id']==iid]) 
        for iid in set(dt['interlocutor_id'] for dt in dialogue_turns)
    ]
    return [{
        'interlocutor_id': iid, 'total_turns': len(dt_list),
        'total_words': sum(len(dt['turn_text'].split()) for dt in dt_list)
    } for iid, dt_list in dt_grouped]

# dialogue_analysis = analyse_dialogue(Dialogues['dialogue_turns'])
```

so that if you had a list of dialogues like *`Dialogues_list = [{'dialogue_id': '000001', ...}, {'dialogue_id': '000002', ...}, ...]`* then you could either build a list of analyses with

```py
dKey = 'dialogue_turns'
dialogues_analyses = [analyse_dialogue(d[dKey]) for d in Dialogues_list]
```

or build a new list of dialogues with analysis included with

```py
dialogues_with_analyses = [{
    **d, 'dialogue_analysis': analyse_dialogue(d['dialogue_turns'])
} for d in Dialogues_list]
```

or add analysis into each dialogue dictionary in `Dialogues_list` with

```py
dKey, aKey = 'dialogue_turns', 'dialogue_analysis'
for di, d in enumerate(Dialogues_list): 
    Dialogues_list[di][aKey] = analyse_dialogue(d[dKey])
```